# Replace with undefined character in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, replace, sql-update

I need to do an `UPDATE` script using the `Replace()` function of Postgres but I don't know the exact string that I have to replace and I'd like to know if there is some way that I can do this similary the `LIKE`operator, using `Wildcards`.
My problem is that I got a table that contains some scripts and at the end of each one there is a tag `<signature>` like this:

> 'SELECT SCRIPT WHATEVER.... < signature>782798e2a92c72b270t920b< signature>'

What I need to do is:

```
UPDATE table SET script = REPLACE(script,'<signature>%<signature>','<signature>1234ABCDEF567890<signature>')
```

Whatever the signature is, I need to replace with a new one defined by me. I know using the '%' doesn't work, it was just to ilustrate the effect i want to perform. Is there any way to do this in Postgres 9.5?

Comment: There is [`regexp_replace` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

Comment: You could use regexp_place, or even a substring.. IE, find the opening tag and substring it to the where the closing tag is found,,

Answer (score 0):

```
 with expr
 as 
 (select 'Hello <signature>thisismysig</signature>'::text as
     full_text, '<signature>'::text as open, 
     '</signature>'::text as close
 )

 select  
   substring(full_text from 
      position(open in full_text)+char_length(open)
      for 
      position(close in full_text)- char_length(open)-position(open in full_text)
   )
```

note: with part added for ease of understanding (hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

Use POSIX regex to do the same thing as other answer (but shorter)

```
 select
 substring('a bunch of other stuff <signature>mysig</signature>' 
   from '<signature>(.*?)</signature>')
```